# Xulrunner 1.9 enable extensions

Tags: xulrunner, browser-addons

I have an xulrunner app. (Beginner level stuff) I want to enable extensions (add-ons) that are running in the current firefox installation. I can copy these extensions to another directory or use them where they are. It doesn't matter to me.

1. What directory do I have to put the extensions in? there is conflicting documentation - does xulrunner try the .default directory of firefox? (windows)
2. What do I have to do in the application.ini to enable extensions? Conflicting docs on that as well.

3.Do I have to set an environment variable?

4. I don't need to update the extensions or let the user manage the extensions, I just want them to run.

Can someone help?

Comment: Good question. I got tired of trying to figure it out and just made it so everything could run in Firefox, for debugging.